# Firefox not sessioning properly

Tags: php, session

I'm currently creating a shoutbox which requires users to be logged in to see. However FF5 (Mozilla Firefox 5) is not allowing members to see it whilst browsers such as IE9 and Chrome are fine with it.

My sessions are set by the login then db.php puts them into a variable:

**e.g.**

```
$_SESSION['ex1'] = "$username";
$_SESSION['ex2'] = "$password";

if (isset($_SESSION['ex1']) && isset($_SESSION['ex2'])) {
   $log = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `id` = '" . $_SESSION['ex1'] . "' AND password = '" . $_SESSION['ex2'] . "'")or die(mysql_error());
   $logged = mysql_fetch_array($log);
}
```

But when I check if the user is online on my shoutbox file:

```
if($logged){

}else{

}
```

On Firefox 5 it says you are logged out where as all other browsers detect that you are logged in. Does anyone know why this happens or what the issue may be?

Comment: warning your code is perceptible to sql injection!

Comment: `$_SESSION['1']` should read `$_SESSION['ex1']`, shouldn't it? You did not use copy/paste, did you?

Comment: @Daniel A. White: vulnerable to $_SESSION ?

Comment: @greg0ire i don't see how where `$username` and `$password` are  set.

Comment: yes that was just a quick example the actual code matches up. and $username and $password are set in the login authentication file which requires db file to work.

Comment: @Daniel A. White: yeah, sorry, these must come from some $_POST variable... (edit: or not O_o) I'm tired

Comment: connection to MYSQL Database, then the code above exampled after line: "My sessions are set by the login then db.php puts them into a variable" from above.
This file is called by each PHP file using require()

Answer (score 1):

It's a very odd issue when the browser affects the result of server side code. Make sure cookies are enables in ff as that might prevent the session id from being saved.